# Upgrade 14.04 to 16.04 failed with some unspecific error

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

I was trying to upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04. I feared it would not work and indeed, it did not work...

I started the upgrade with the command

```
sudo update-manager -d
```

and it downloaded about 3000 packages (1 hour) and then it said something like

```
There were errors
```

(without installing the downloaded packages). I cannot reproduce the error message, because when I try to upgrade again with the command from above I see a small window ('Software Updater') saying 'Checking for updates...', but this window is greyed out and does not respond.

I guess I have to buy a new computer? Or is there a way to continue the upgrade...?

Addendum: After a long waiting time a window popped up asking me for a partial upgrade. Here is what it says:

```
Run a partial upgrade, to install as many updates as possible
This can be caused by:
* A previous upgrade which didn't complete
* ...
```

Of course a previous upgrade which didn't complete...

Comment: does it give detail on the partial upgrade?

Comment: First of all, you never need to buy a new computer; just back up the files you care about, wipe the disk, and install Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: @cat: But then what are upgrades for?

Comment: For when you have a working system? But if you reboot, you are likely to be met with black

Comment: No, reboot works fine, no upgrade at all has been started.

Comment: run the partial, it may do a full upgrade.